# report viewer in visual studio 2015 is not drop on form in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

I have installed reportviewer 11.0.0 and it is showing in toolbox but when I drag it and drop on my web form nothing happen. report viewer is not showing on form and also there is no code of it showing in source code of page. Also when I try to add report from add new item there is no option for selecting report or report wizard. whats wrong with it. please someone help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download and install MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35747

Answer (score 0):

Run the installer of visual studio. Select modify option, on next page select SQL data tools. After modify it restart visual studio. problem is solved